# A double symbolic integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

I am trying to calculate some integrals, for example:

```
a = 1/sqrt(2); 
b = -5;
c = 62;
d = 1;
f = exp(-x^2-y^2)*(erfc((sym(a) + 1/(x^2+y^2)*(sym(b)*x+sym(d)*y))*sqrt((x^2+y^2)*sym(10.^(c/10))))...
                 + erfc((sym(a) - 1/(x^2+y^2)*(sym(b)*x+sym(d)*y))*sqrt((x^2+y^2)*sym(10.^(c/10)))));    
h = int(int(f,x,-Inf,Inf),y,-Inf,Inf);
```

It will occur error like this:

> Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.

Then, I try to use `vpa`to calculate that integral,and get the result like this

```
vpa(int(int(f,x,-Inf,Inf),y,-Inf,Inf),5)
numeric::int(numeric::int(exp(- x^2 - y^2)*(erfc(((6807064429273519*x^2)/4294967296 + (6807064429273519*y^2)/4294967296)^(1/2)*(2^(1/2)/2 + (5*x - y)/(x^2 + y^2))) + erfc(((6807064429273519*x^2)/4294967296 + (6807064429273519*y^2)/4294967296)^(1/2)*(2^(1/2)/2 - (5*x - y)/(x^2 + y^2)))), x == -Inf..Inf), y == -Inf..Inf)
```

I already tried to change the interval `[-Inf,Inf]` to `[-100,100]`, and get the same above result:

```
numeric::int(numeric::int(exp(- x^2 - y^2)*(erfc(((6807064429273519*x^2)/4294967296 + (6807064429273519*y^2)/4294967296)^(1/2)*(2^(1/2)/2 + (5*x - y)/(x^2 + y^2))) + erfc(((6807064429273519*x^2)/4294967296 + (6807064429273519*y^2)/4294967296)^(1/2)*(2^(1/2)/2 - (5*x - y)/(x^2 + y^2)))), x == -100..100), y == -100..100)
```

My question is why `vpa` in this case could not return to a real value?
There are something wrong in above Matlab code? (I, myself, could not find the bug so far)
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that there is an analytic solution to this integral so using [`int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html) may not be a good choice. In some cases `vpa` can be used to for a numeric solution. When this fails (by returning a call to itself) it may be for several reason: the integral may not exist, the integral may converge too slowly, singularities may cause issues, the integrand may be highly oscillatory or non-smooth, etc. Mathematica also struggles with this integral.

You can try calculating the integral numerically using [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html):

```
a = 1/sqrt(2);
b = -5;
c = 62;
d = 1;
f = @(x,y)exp(-x.^2-y.^2).*(erfc((a + 1./(x.^2+y.^2).*(b*x+d*y)).*sqrt((x.^2+y.^2)*10^(c/10)))...
          +erfc((a - 1./(x.^2+y.^2).*(b*x+d*y)).*sqrt((x.^2+y.^2)*10^(c/10))));
h = integral2(f,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf)
```

which returns `5.790631184403967`. This compares well with Mathematica's numerical integration using `NIntegrate`. You can try specifying smaller absolute and relative tolerances for `integral2` to get more accurate values, but this will result in much slower compute times.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, could you explain more your answer that "You can try specifying smaller absolute and relative tolerances for integral2 to get more accurate values". I did not get your point here. 
Just one more thing, in the case, for example, c is vector, i.e., c = [ 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 ] (or a long vector). How could we use "integral2"? Because I already search and try "integral2" for a c vector, but it seems "integral2" does not work with a vector.

Comment: As far as tolerances go, see the documentation for `integral2`. You can just specify `integral2(f,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf,'AbsTol',1e-10,'RelTol',1e-10)` for example. I don't know what your `c` vector represents. Do you just want to solve the integral one for each element in `c`? If so, then just use a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Put "for loop" is solution I also though.

Comment: @StevenHuynh: I don't understand your second sentence due grammar errors. Were you able to solve your problem? By the way, I'm Belgian too (the french speaking kind though).

Comment: I am sorry for typing error. Using "for - end" loop was  the solution which I also thought. It worked, although I have to use many loops because not only c is vector in my program. Thank you again for your kind help :)

Comment: @horchler congratulations on 15k *and* the gold [matlab]:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Thanks much!